# Trying to return date as day of the week numbered value

Tags: date, plsql

I'm trying to return my date_column (dtcreated) as a numbered value in my select statement so that way I can display the number of total orders for each day of the week as well as what day its on (i.e. Monday etc.) except its not returning. Can someone double check my date function code and tell me what I'm doing wrong because its not returning.

```
create or replace function DAY_ORD_SF
(basket_id IN number)
return number

IS

basket_iID  number(5);
basket_dt   date;
num_of_ord  number;
day_of_week number;
week_day    varchar2(10);

cursor bb IS select idbasket, dtcreated from bb_basket where idbasket=basket_id;

BEGIN
    open bb;
    fetch bb into basket_iID, basket_dt;

    SELECT COUNT(BASKET_iID), TO_DATE(BASKET_DT,'D') INTO NUM_OF_ORD, DAY_OF_WEEK FROM BB_BASKET WHERE IDBASKET=BASKET_iID;

    IF DAY_OF_WEEK = 1 THEN
        WEEK_DAY := 'Sunday';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Orders for ' || week_day || ' is ' || NUM_OF_ORD || '.' );
    ELSIF DAY_OF_WEEK = 2 THEN
        WEEK_DAY := 'Monday';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Orders for ' || WEEK_DAY || ' is ' || NUM_OF_ORD || '.');
    ELSIF DAY_OF_WEEK = 3 THEN
        WEEK_DAY := 'Tuesday';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Orders for ' || WEEK_DAY || ' is ' || NUM_OF_ORD || '.');
    ELSIF DAY_OF_WEEK = 4 THEN
        WEEK_DAY := 'Wednesday';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Orders for ' || WEEK_DAY || ' is ' || NUM_OF_ORD || '.');
    ELSIF DAY_OF_WEEK = 5 THEN
        WEEK_DAY := 'Thursday';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Orders for ' || WEEK_DAY || ' is ' || NUM_OF_ORD || '.');
    ELSIF DAY_OF_WEEK = 6 THEN
        WEEK_DAY := 'Friday';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Orders for ' || WEEK_DAY || ' is ' || NUM_OF_ORD || '.');
    ELSIF DAY_OF_WEEK = 7 THEN
        WEEK_DAY := 'Saturday';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Orders for ' || WEEK_DAY || ' is ' || NUM_OF_ORD || '.');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no RETURN statement in your code. You might try putting

```
RETURN DAY_OF_WEEK;
```

just before the `END;` of the function.

Share and enjoy.